# Is "issue is working" correct expression?

Tags: expressions

In the bug report comment:

> Today this issue is working fine for me.

I saw this phrase and got confused. I would rather say "This issue resolved" or "I haven't noticed this issue today". 
Is that correct expression? Are my variants valid?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a bug report or something similar in which an "issue" (i.e., a problem) was reported. If that's the case, you wouldn't want to say that the issue is working fine, because the issue is the problem. Your examples are fine, except that you would need the word "is" (or similar) in the first one (e.g., "This issue is resolved.").

Comment: What @Andy said. Problems/issues can be *outstanding, resolved*, etc., but strictly speaking they can't "work". What works fine for you is some *procedure* that didn't work for someone else (that's why they reported an *issue* concerning the procedure).

Comment: Thank you for prompt responses, guys! 
Andy,  the verb "is" required because "resolved" is an adverb. Am I right? Or "resolved" plays adjective role in this case?

Comment: As someone who works in technology, I just want to add that while the others are correct that this sentence is not grammatically *perfect*, it's pretty typical of the kind of English you'll find in a hastily-written comment on a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression can sound natural, but context is important.

Consider the following definitions:

> **Issue** *noun*
>   1.2 Problems or difficulties, especially with a service or facility.
>   *‘a small number of users are experiencing connectivity issues’*
>   2.2 [count noun] Each of a regular series of publications.
>   *‘the December issue of the magazine’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/issue)
>
> **Work** *verb*
>   2 (of a machine or system) function, especially properly or effectively.
>   *‘Although it is of the same size as an old sewing machine, it still works fine.’*
>   3 (of a plan or method) have the desired result or effect.
>   *‘We had a great time stalking redfish in two feet of water with fly or spinning rod, both methods worked for us.’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/work)

In technical circles, it would be natural to take definition 1.2 of *issue* along with definition 2 of *work*. The sentence is awkward because a *working issue* is an oxymoron in this context. Your alternatives are better, though the first should have something between "issue" and "resolved" (e.g. "This issue: resolved").

Now consider the other pair of definitions (with definition 3 of *work* pushed a little further to mean that one is [satisfied with an outcome](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/works+for+me)). An editor who was previously dissatisfied with the way an issue of a magazine was presented, but has since changed her mind, could conceivably utter the sentence you quoted.

Comment: I agree, my fault, I didn't give any context.

Comment: I think, first phrase should sounds like: This issue has been resolved. It is like "the wall has been painted". I think, issue cannot do anything with itself, so someone has to take care of it and this is main reason for passive voice.